# Cannot connect to remote jupyter server from VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I need some advice. So I am a big fan of VS Code and I always use its embedded notebooks. I built a remote Jupyter Server on Oracle Cloud hoping I could [connect from vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server). To create the server I based on this [article](https://gianniceresa.com/2019/12/jupyter-sandbox-in-an-oracle-cloud-compute-instance/), but migrating as advised by Jupyter to [JupyterServer](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators/migrate-from-nbserver.html). I've also used miniconda isntead of venv.

The server seems to work correctly, I can access it from my browser and in my Windows Terminal SSH, open Jupyter Lab, create and run noteboooks in it, etc. The problem is when I try to use it with VS Code, when I try to specify de Jupyter Server for connections, it allows me to do it, it even prompts me that it is an insecure connection (I use self signed ssl certificate), and it does mark **Jupyter Server: Remote** BUT, when I try to select my interpreter, change my kernel, it only shows my local conda envs. if I run `!hostname` it shows me my local hostname, not my remotes, it isn't really connecting or using the remote Jupyter server to run the cells.

I've looked around and can`t find a way to make it work, I really want it to work with VS Code, any help?

Answer (score 0):

This has no impact on the actual use of jupyter. Your confusion is actually a misunderstanding caused by the definition of names.

As stated in the [official document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server), when you connect to a remote server, **everything runs in the server ather than the local computer**.

At present, there is an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/10601) for changing the naming on GitHub, which you can read in detail.